# Looping google maps markers with json encoded array

Tags: php, google-maps, json

Really need help here. I convert an array with json_encode to be able to loop through the lats/longs of the searchresult in a google map below. The map loads fine if i just use a normal marker, and if I echo the json encoded array I get:

```
["55.7171, 13.2354","55.6411, 13.2122"]
```

The Php code below (ignore most of it except the markers part, just giving you an idea of how it´s used).

```
<?php
    if (isset($search_result)) {

        $markers = array();

        // Looping through the results and displaying appropriate data.
        foreach ($search_result as $result) {
            ?>
            <li><?= $result['first_name']; ?></li>
            <li><?= $result['last_name']; ?></li>
            <li><?= $result['address']; ?></li>
            <li><img width="80" height="80" src="<?php echo file_exists($result['profile_picture'])? $result['profile_picture'] : $img_profile_def; ?>"></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php?userid=<?= $result['id']; ?>">View This User</a></li><br><br>
    <?php
        $markers[] = $result['latitude'] . ', ' . $result['longitude'];
        }
    }
?>
```

The Javascript at the bottom of the script initializing the map etc. I get a map with this code but no markers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var markers = <?php echo json_encode($markers); ?>;

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo $area_coords; ?> );

    var mapOptions = {
        center:myLatLng,
        zoom:15,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        map:map,
        position:position

    });
    }
}

initialize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're passing a string as the LatLng parameter instead of two floats...perhaps you could change your JSON so that it's:
[[lat,lng],[lat,lng]...] like so:

```
$markers[] = [$result['latitude'],$result['longitude']];
```

and then

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0],markers[i][1]);
```

Comment: Can´t try it until about 15 hours but will see if it works then. Hopefully it´s just the stringproblem, it would at least mean that the rest of the code is okay.

Comment: the rest looks pretty standard. I'd also suggest adding your markers to an array when you create them, it'll help with things like clearing the map, and managing click events on the markers...see here:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#RemovingOverlays